# setConnectTimeout causes hang?

Tags: time, out

hi im trying to test a proxy but if i set setConnectTimeout over 1500 it causes to programe to hang it just dies nothing gets printed my processor and memery arint doing much it just dies does anyone know of a solution for this the code is
HttpURLConnection inSite = (HttpURLConnection) site.openConnection(proxy);
inSite.setConnectTimeout(2000); //if set below 1500 its fine

this is a real prob as most proxies are too slow to respon in this time thanks

Answer (score 0):

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

```
public void sixtymin() {

    final Runnable logger= new Runnable() {//instansiation

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());//code to execute
        }
            //You application logic as shown in the question
        };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> loggerHandle =
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(logger, 0, 5, SECONDS );//action,delay before first run,delay between,unit
```

this was the solution the above code prints time every 5 secs so i used it to kill process ofter timeout